# Iterate ruby array to javascript array with passing javascript variable to ruby method

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I want to iterate ruby array in javascript code. How can i pass `i` variable to `labels_json` array?

```
var offer_categories_names = <%= raw(offer_categories_names) %>;
var offer_sub_categories_list=new Array(offer_categories_names.length-1);
for (var i = 0; i < offer_categories_names.length; i++) {
  //console.log(offer_categories_names[i] + i);
  if (offer_categories_names[i] == parent_dropdown_value) {
    //iterator i instead of 0...9
    child_options_array = <%= raw(labels_json[0]) %>;
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1):

You can’t pass javascript variable to ruby code. To solve this problem, loop through the ruby array instead of javascript array:

```
<% offer_categories_names.each_with_index do |offer_categories_name, i| %>
  if ('<%= offer_categories_name %>' == parent_dropdown_value) {
    child_options_array = <%= raw labels_json[i].to_json %>;
  }
<% end %>
```

Comment: @HamidIqbal You're welcome. Would you mark my answer as an answer and upvote it? :)